# Infinitely many degeneracy of Landau level: Countable or Uncountable?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, magnetic-fields, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, hilbert-space

Description of Landau levels can be found in many standard textbooks of quantum mechanics and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_quantization). Two ubiquitous solutions apply either the symmetric gauge $\vec{A}=(-\frac{1}{2}By,\frac{1}{2}Bx,0)$ or the Landau gauge $\vec{A}=(-By,0,0)$ to the Schrödinger equation.
(1) Taking $\{\hat{H},\hat{L}_z\}$ as the complete set of conserved quantities, the symmetric gauge solution often calls for confluent hypergeometric equation in the end, which gives $E=(2n_\rho+m+|m|+1)\hbar\omega_L$, in which $n_\rho=0,1,2,\cdots,\,m=0,\pm1,\pm2,\cdots$.
(2) The above Landau gauge solution diagonalizes $\hat{p}_x$ and reduces the problem to a 1D harmonic oscillator in $y$-direction with completely not fixed equilibrium point $y_0=-\frac{p_x}{qB}$.

We know if the 2D plane in which the electron moves is finite, the degeneracy is the number of flux quanta in the plane. However, if the plane is infinitely large, then the degeneracy of each landau level should be infinity. Intriguingly, **this degeneracy appears to be a countable infinity for (1) since $m$ takes discrete values, while being uncountable for (2) since $y_0$ is in continuum.** How to resolve this?

One might say this is probably not physically observable, but I guess it is hard to deny this is a well-defined question in its own right.

Comment: Can you suggest an experiment that can measure the cardinality of a degeneracy? If not, there is a good reason to exclude this one from the set of physical questions.

Comment: You are making confusion between the degeneracy of an eigenvalue (the dimension of its eigenvectors space) and the number of eigenvalues (characterized by the so-called spectrum). The degeneracy of an eigenvalue will always be at most countable on a separable Hilbert space (it will always have an at most countable orthonormal basis); the spectrum may be discrete (countable) or continuous(uncountable), or even both, depending on the operator. For example, the Hamiltonian for a free particle has purely continuous spectrum, the one for the Harmonic oscillator purely discrete.

Comment: @yuggib I see what you mean. But I reckon it doesn't invalidate my question because here it is exactly the $p_x$ continuum that gives the degeneracy of case (2).

Comment: There is an infinite degeneracy in the symmetric gauge too. See this interesting [paper](http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/221a/landau.pdf), for instance formula $3.5$

Comment: @huotuichang yes, the degeneracy is given by the free operator in one variable, but the Hilbert space is separable, so the cardinality of the degeneracy is still countable.

Comment: @yuggib what do you mean by separable Hilbert space? And why must the degeneracy of its eigenvalue be countable?

Comment: @huotuichang an Hilbert space is called separable if it admits a countable orthonormal basis. Every Hilbert space that is physically relevant is separable. Since the space of eigenvectors can be at most of the dimensionality of the Hilbert space they belong to (because the eigenvectors MUST belong to the space), they have at most the same cardinality, which is, by definition, countable.

Comment: @yuggib Is a free particle's Hilbert space separable? I think it admits an uncountable basis.

Comment: @huotuichang Yes it is. The "eigenvectors" of position are not real eigenvectors because they do not belong to the Hilbert space. The continuous part of the spectrum does not admit eigenvectors. However the space is the usual $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$, that is separable.

Comment: @yuggib I see. But please tell me what $L^2$ means? I forget the notation. sth. square integrable?  And do you mean that, although $p_x$ is in continuum, this problem itself (and any other physically relevant ones) anyhow must have a 'separable Hilbert space', so the degeneracy should be countable? This sounds a little unfathomable because the $p_x$ stuff still get me preoccupied. Maybe you're not telling me everything, maybe I'm stupid... Any reference on your statement that every Hilbert space that is physically relevant is separable?

Comment: @yuggib If you're sure about your explanation, why not adding necessary details and making it a clear answer underneath? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding my comments: Quantum mechanics is formulated in separable Hilbert spaces, i.e. Hilbert spaces with a countable orthonormal basis. The usual space describing a three dimensional particle is the space of square integrable functions $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$. This is separable, as well.

On separable Hilbert spaces, the spectrum of a self-adjoint operator has a continuous and discrete part. Eigenvectors that belong to the Hilbert space are associated only with the eigenvalues of the discrete spectrum. It is possible to formally associate eigenvectors with the continuous spectrum, but they do not belong to the Hilbert space.

Given an eigenvalue (of the discrete spectrum), it has a multiplicity determined by the dimension of the Hilbert subspace spanned by its eigenvectors. This subspace is always contained in the Hilbert space itself, so it is also at most separable, i.e. it admits also at most a countable orthonormal basis.

To get a concrete example (borrowing from another answer): an harmonic oscillator operator $H_x=-\Delta_x + x^2$, with $x\in\mathbb{R}$, on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ has a purely discrete spectrum, with each eigenvalue of multiplicity 1. If we consider the same operator but acting on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)=L^2_x(\mathbb{R})\otimes L^2_y(\mathbb{R})$, i.e. it acts only on the $x$ variable but not on the $y$, it has still the same discrete spectrum but with infinite multiplicity. This is because if $\phi_\lambda(x)$ is an eigenfunction of $H$ (on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$) with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then for any $\psi\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ we have that on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$:
$$H_x(\phi_\lambda(x)\psi(y))=\lambda\phi_\lambda(x)\psi(y)$$
i.e. $\phi_\lambda(x)\psi(y)$ is an eigenvector of $H$. The multiplicity has become infinite, but its cardinality is still countable since it is the same cardinality of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, which is countable.

The fact that an operator acts like the multiplication by an "uncountable" variable (i.e. defined for any point of $\mathbb{R}$ which is uncountable) does not mean the associated Hilbert space where it acts on is uncountable, because the space itself is a space of functions.

Comment: Your answer makes perfect sense. Clear enough. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The Hamiltonian as given in
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_quantization is\ (note that $x$ and $y$
are interchanged) is
\begin{equation*}
H=\frac{p_{x}^{2}}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}m\omega _{c}^{2}(x-\frac{\hbar p_{y}}{%
m\omega _{c}})^{2},
\end{equation*}
acting in $\mathcal{H}=L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{2},dxdy)$.Then, since
\begin{equation*}
x-\frac{\hbar p_{y}}{m\omega _{c}}=\exp [-ip_{x}\frac{\hbar p_{y}}{m\omega
_{c}}]x\exp [+ip_{x}\frac{\hbar p_{y}}{m\omega _{c}}]=U(p_{y})xU^{-1}(p_{y}),
\end{equation*}
we have
\begin{equation*}
H=U(p_{y})\hat{H}U^{-1}(p_{y}),\;\hat{H}=\{\frac{p_{x}^{2}}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}%
m\omega _{c}^{2}x^{2}\}\otimes \mathsf{I}_{y}=\{\sum_{n}E_{n}\mid \varphi
_{n}><\varphi _{n}\mid \}\otimes \mathsf{I}_{y},
\end{equation*}
where $\mathsf{I}_{y}$ is the unit operator acting in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R},dy)$
.Thus $H$ and $\hat{H}$ are unitarily related and hence have, as operators
in $\mathcal{H}$, the same spectrum. But, although
\begin{equation*}
h=\frac{p_{x}^{2}}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}m\omega _{c}^{2}x^{2}
\end{equation*}
acting in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R},dx)$ has discrete spectrum, this is no longer
true for $\hat{H}$ acting in $\mathcal{H}$. Thus, as an operator in $
\mathcal{H}$, $\hat{H}$ has no discrete spectrum at all. Only if we make a
direct integral decomposition (possible since $y$ does not occur in $H$ or $
\hat{H}$), here a Fourier transformation in the $y$-variable, $L^{2}(\mathbb{
R},dy)\rightarrow L^{2}(\mathbb{R},dk)$, $p_{y}\rightarrow k$, we obtain on
each fiber, labelled by $k$, the operator $h$, which has discrete spectrum,
\begin{equation*}
\hat{H}\rightarrow \int^{\oplus }dk\hat{H}(k),\;\hat{H}(k)=h.
\end{equation*}
Thus $h$, acting in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R},dx)$, has discrete spectrum but  $\hat{%
H}$, acting in $\mathcal{H}$ does not.

Comment: It seems to me that in your example $\hat{H}$ has a discrete spectrum (the same of the harmonic oscillator), simply it has infinitely degenerate eigenvalues, because of the factorization in the two variables.

Comment: No, H^ certainly has continuous spectrum only. It decomposes into a (countable) number of branches, each starting at one of the eigenvalues of $h$. For details of such spectral properties, see, for instance, the volumes of "Methods of modern mathematical physics" by Reed and Simon.

Comment: As you wrote it, i.e. as the tensor product of an harmonic oscillator in one variable and the identity operator in the other, it indeed has discrete spectrum, with infinite degeneracy. Let $\phi_\lambda(x)$ be an eigenfunction of $h$ corresp to $\lambda$; $\psi(y)$ any function in $L^2(\mathbb{R},dy)$. Then $\phi_\lambda(x)\psi(y)$ is an eigenfunction of $\hat{H}$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Comment: For the general form of the spectrum of a tensor product see http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2035080?uid=3738736&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21104196837501. Thus the spectrum $σ(A⊗B)$ of $A⊗B$ is $σ(A)⊗σ(B)$. In your case $σ(B)=1$ so you are right and I made a mistake (what I said is for the direct sum). But you can see that things remain countable since the $ψ(y)$ can be expressed in terms of a (countable) basis of ${L^2}(R,dy)$.

Comment: Yes of course, I was not questioning the countability. It's only that in these spectral things it is better to be careful ;-)

Comment: I should add that a similar situation occurs with surface states on the plane interface of vacuum and certain dielectrics.